# Method of moments estimator for $\theta$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $ X_1,X_2,...,X_n $ be a random sample from a discrete distribution with probability mass function given by 
$P(X=0)=\dfrac{1-\theta}{2};P(X=1)=\dfrac{1}{2};P(X=2)=\dfrac{\theta}{2}$;$0\leq\theta\leq1$

Find the method of moments estimator for $\theta$;

I calculated $E(X)= 0 \cdot\dfrac{1-\theta}{2} + 1 \cdot\dfrac{1}{2}+ 2\cdot\dfrac{\theta}{2}=\theta+\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\bar x=\theta+\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\bar x+\dfrac{1}{2}= {\hat\theta } $

My solution doesnt matches up with my material. Did i do any mistake here? Please someone tell me.

Comment: Somehow, $$\bar x=\theta+\dfrac{1}{2}$$ and $$\bar x+\dfrac{1}{2}= {\hat\theta } $$ do not quite match, don't you think? :-) My impression is that there is nothing more to this question.

Comment: Omg yes so silly. That is just typo here. So there's nothing more? $0<\theta<1$ doesn't matter here ?

Comment: Nope. The method of moment definitely yields $\hat\theta=\bar x-\frac12$. True, as you noted, the result could be anywhere in $[-\frac12,\frac32]$ while we know that $\theta$ is actually in $(0,1)$, but this is inherent to the method, nothing to do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of moments consists in solving the system of equations made by the equality of empirical and theoretical moments. If we restrict us to the first moment (the expected value), we get indeed $\Bbb E X_1 = 1/2 + \theta$, which we equate to the empirical mean $\overline{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Thus, the following estimator $\hat\theta_n$ is obtained for $\theta$:
$$
\hat\theta_n = \overline{X}_n - \frac{1}{2} 
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \frac{1}{2}\right) .
$$
Using the law of large numbers, one shows that is estimator is consistent (convergence $\hat\theta_n {\to} \Bbb \theta$ in probability). Since this estimator is unbiased (expected value $\Bbb E\hat\theta_n = \theta$), the quadratic risk is equal to the estimator's variance, i.e. $\text{var}\hat\theta_n = \frac{-\theta^2 + \theta + 1/4}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to know there is nothing more eh?